# Apply a function on each element of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, apply

Last year I used a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861182/command-inside-mapply-command-in-mvtnorm-package) that produces the different values of cumulative probability of a trivariate normal distribution, when the parameters change value simultaneously according to a function. I used this code:

```
library(mvtnorm)
Y <- mapply(function(x,y,z) 
  pmvnorm(mean  = c(18, 12.72, (18*(x+y) +12.72*z)),
          sigma = {
            s1 <- matrix(c(5.7, 0, 5.7*(x+y),
                           0, 30.38, 30.38*z,
                           5.7*(x+y), 30.38*z, 5.7*(x+y)^2+30.38*(z)^2),
                         3)
            replace(s1,s1==0, 1e-20)
          },
          lower = c(15, -Inf, p+15*y),
          upper = c(Inf, 15, Inf)),
  m1, m2, m3)
```

where m1,m2,m3 (associated to x,y and z) are vectors already defined. As they are 1x10 vectors, the code produce a vector 1x10.

Now what if m1,m2 and m3 are matrices?I produce three matrices 10x36 with this code:

```
a <- 5
b <- 5
vals <- rep(0:a, (b+1))
x <- rep(1:(a+b), ((a+1)*(b+1)))
c <- matrix(pmin(x, vals[rep(1:((a+1)*(b+1)), each = (a+b))]), nrow = (a+b))
m1 <- c
d1 <- matrix(rep(c(1:(a+b)), ((a+1)*(b+1))), ncol=((a+1)*(b+1)), nrow=(a+b),      byrow=F)
d2 <- matrix(rep(rowSums(expand.grid(0:a, 0:b)), (a+b)), ncol=((a+1)*(b+1)),  nrow=(a+b), byrow=T)
d3 <- pmax((d1-d2),0)
d4 <- matrix(rep(0:a, b+1), ncol=((a+1)*(b+1)), nrow=(a+b), byrow=T)
d5 <- a-d4
d6 <- pmin(d3,d5)
d7 <- matrix(nrow = (a+b), ncol = ((a+1)*(b+1)))
for (i in 1:(a+b)) {
  for (j in 1:((a+1)*(b+1))) {
    d7[i,j] <- a
  }
}
d8 <- pmin(d7,d1)
d <- d6-d8
m2 <- d
e1 <- pmin(d1,d2)
e2 <- e1-d4
e3 <- matrix(nrow = (a+b), ncol = ((a+1)*(b+1)))
for (i in 1:(a+b)) {
  for (j in 1:((a+1)*(b+1))) {
    e3[i,j] <- 0
  }
}
e <- pmax(e2, e3)
m3 <- e
r <- 0.04
k <- rep(rowSums(expand.grid(0:a, 0:b)))
p <- k*(15*(1-r)^(k-1))
p <- t(matrix(rep(p,(a+b)), ncol=(a+b), nrow=((a+1)*(b+1))))
```

Now I want to produce a matrix 10x36 where each element is the the value of the cumulative probability of a trivariate normal distribution, where the mean and the covariance matrix depends on that elements of the matrices m1 m2 and m3.
I have tried again with the code:

```
Y <- mapply(function(x,y,z) 
  pmvnorm(mean  = c(18, 12.72, (18*(x+y) +12.72*z)),
          sigma = {
            s1 <- matrix(c(5.7, 0, 5.7*(x+y),
                           0, 30.38, 30.38*z,
                           5.7*(x+y), 30.38*z, 5.7*(x+y)^2+30.38*(z)^2),
                         3)
            replace(s1, s1==0, 1e-20)
          },
          lower = c(15, -Inf, p+15*y),
          upper = c(Inf, 15, Inf)),
  m1, m2, m3)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in checkmvArgs(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = mean, corr = corr,     : 
  at least one element of ‘lower’ is larger than ‘upper’
Warning message:
In cbind(lower, upper, mean) :
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2).
```

Where is the error?

Comment: I suggest my edited code to make it perhaps a little more readable (e.g., indentation, admittedly subjective). I assume you are using `library(mvtnorm)`, so I added that as well. Please correct it if I am incorrect. (And please make sure you include it yourself.) If your previous SO question/answer is relevant contextually, it might be useful to include the link, but it's good that this question is otherwise self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, *and* `p` are all dimensioned 10x36, I'm inferring that you are intending to use each individual value of `p` instead of the whole matrix each time. For example, if you step into the call to `pmvnorm`, you'll see:

```
Y <- mapply(function(x,y,z) {
  browser()
  pmvnorm(mean  = c(18, 12.72, (18*(x+y) +12.72*z)),
          sigma = {
            s1 <- matrix(c(5.7, 0, 5.7*(x+y),
                           0, 30.38, 30.38*z,
                           5.7*(x+y), 30.38*z, 5.7*(x+y)^2+30.38*(z)^2),
                         3)
            replace(s1, s1==0, 1e-20)
          },
          lower = c(15, -Inf, p+15*y),
          upper = c(Inf, 15, Inf))
}, m1, m2, m3)
# debug at c:/Users/r2/AppData/Local/Temp/foo.R!12268ZNM#3: pmvnorm(mean = c(18, 12.72, (18 * (x + y) + 12.72 * z)), sigma = {
#     s1 <- matrix(c(5.7, 0, 5.7 * (x + y), 0, 30.38, 30.38 * z, 
#         5.7 * (x + y), 30.38 * z, 5.7 * (x + y)^2 + 30.38 * (z)^2), 
#         3)
#     replace(s1, s1 == 0, 1e-20)
# }, lower = c(15, -Inf, p + 15 * y), upper = c(Inf, 15, Inf))
# Browse[2]> 
x
# [1] 0
```

This is expected.

```
# Browse[2]> 
dim(p)
# [1] 10 36
```

I think this should instead be:

```
# Browse[2]>
p
# [1] 0
```

In which case, you can start to fix the problem by adding `p` to the list of arguments:

```
pm <- p   # 'pm' is 'p-matrix' (?)
rm(p)
```

(I did this to remove the ambiguity of having `p` both inside and outside the call to `mapply`. It works anyway, but troubleshooting a closure where you aren't certain *which* instance of the variable is being used can be frustrating and certainly not intuitive.)

```
set.seed(2)
Y <- mapply(function(x,y,z,p)
  pmvnorm(mean  = c(18, 12.72, (18*(x+y) +12.72*z)),
          sigma = {
            s1 <- matrix(c(5.7, 0, 5.7*(x+y),
                           0, 30.38, 30.38*z,
                           5.7*(x+y), 30.38*z, 5.7*(x+y)^2+30.38*(z)^2),
                         3)
            replace(s1, s1==0, 1e-20)
          },
          lower = c(15, -Inf, p+15*y),
          upper = c(Inf, 15, Inf)),
  m1, m2, m3, pm)
```

One problem you'll see is that `mapply` has returned a vector.

```
head(Y)
# [1] 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.2957254
length(Y)
# [1] 360
dim(Y)
# NULL
```

This can be fixed by assigning the same dimensionality as the input variable. (Since you called `matrix` with the default of `byrow=FALSE`, this works as-is. If you had done `byrow=TRUE`, you'd need to adjust here.)

```
dim(Y) <- dim(m1)
dim(Y)
# [1] 10 36
Y[1:4,1:5]
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
# [2,] 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.5914508 0.0000000 0.0000000
# [3,] 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.5914508 0.5914508 0.0000000
# [4,] 0.2957254 0.2957254 0.5914508 0.5914508 0.5914508
```

Comment: thank you so much!It works and I obtain what I wanted! thank you again